# Multiple URLs in one WebView

Tags: java, android, url, button, android-activity

I want to make two buttons and one WebView, but somehow my app stops. I can't find mistake. Could someone help me?

Main Java:

```
public void setButtononClick(View v) {
    String url = null;

    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            url="https://www.delfi.lt";
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://delfi.lt")));
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            url= "https://www.youtube.com";
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com")));
            break;
    }

    Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)); startActivity(intent);
    }}
```

WebView ACC JAVA

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    // Get reference of WebView from layout/webviewex.xml
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    // Get URL from Intent
    String URL = getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");

    // Load website
    webView.loadUrl(URL);
}
```

Maybe someone could help me? I think i tried everything.

Comment: Could you share the error or stacktrace in the original post?

Comment: There is no errors. Only "your app has stoped"

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String url;

        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
               url="https://www.delfi.lt";
               launchBrowserWithUri(Uri.parse(url))
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
               url= "https://www.youtube.com";
                   launchBrowserWithUri(Uri.parse(url))
                break;
        }



Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    if (getActivity() != null && launchBrowser.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
```

Comment: I edited my code, could you look at it please?
Because now app do not crash, but it is blank page... No buttons,nothing.